# How does one make a podspec honor the "head:" argument?

Tags: objective-c, git, github, cocoapods

When I try to specify that I want to pull the latest version of a pod, according to the `Cocoapods` [official docs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod), I list it in my podfile like this:

```
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', :head
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I'm noticing that most pods just pull version thats listed in their podspec, not the latest commit as desired. What declarations does a `podspec` need to get `head:` to work as intended?

Comment: If using `:head` is actually not pulling the most recent commit when you run `pod install` or `pod update` this could be a bug. I would encourage you to checkout the [issue tracker](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues?state=open) and submit one if there isn't a similar issue.

Comment: To be clear, when you used the `:head` option CocoaPods uses the podspec of the latest version (available in the specs repo) with the source of the head commit. You can confirm this because the version printed by the command line tool should terminate with the `(HEAD)` note.

Comment: If you would like to use the podspec of the head you can use the `:git` option as described here http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod.

Comment: @Fabio: the :git option is not described on the linked page.

Comment: So there's actually no solution for this!?

Answer (score 1):

The `:head` option is deprecated. Use `:git` instead:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git'
```